# Clear AIR Mobile application data in IntelliJ

Tags: apache-flex, air, intellij-idea, flash-builder, flex-mobile

I'm developing a mobile AIR application using IntelliJ.

When debugging in Flash Builder there is an option to clear to application data on each (debug) launch of the ADL (see screenshot below) However, I can't find this setting in IntelliJ or some ADL parameter to force a clear on each new debug session. I was wondering if such an option exist in IntelliJ or ADL.

*A little background*: I'm using the PersistanceManager in the application to store some user settings and I want to be able to start the application without the saved settings from my previous run. Using this setting in Flash Builder does the trick, but I'm having no luck with IntelliJ.

[image: Flash Builder debug settings window]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, never had to do that before, but I believe that if you do a "clean" before rebuilding, that should clear out the PersistanceManager.

Comment: Do you mean by "clean", cleaning the system cache in IntelliJ? I tried that but that didn't work.

Comment: No, I mean a clean as in with maven which deletes the build folder.  There should be something like "bin" in intelliJ.  Try deleting that folder in between to see if that works.

Comment: There is no "clean" in intellij.. And not all air apps are using maven

Answer (score 0):

Yes im still trying to find a solution for this.

The reason this happens is because when you are testing on the device, for some reason IntelliJ sends an uninstall command to the device so it wipes clean everything.

I tried to run my own compiler arguments, but the uninstall command has higher priority so i can't cancel it yet. I think a good solution could be using ant tasks: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=anttasks_1.html